# Select2 Selected Values Over Written

Tags: jquery-select2

I am trying to use select2 as a tag entry.  The values are there when it loads but when a value is added the current values get cleared.

```
var $serverType = $("#id_server_type");
current_values = ['Oracle DB'].map( function(item) {
  $serverType.append('<option selected value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
});
$.getJSON("/api/server-types/", function(data){
    $serverType.html('');
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
      $.each(val, function(index, value) {
        $serverType.append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
      })
    });
});
$serverType.select2({
  tags: true,
  minimumInputLength: 0
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the current values gets cleared"?

Comment: That there is the current selected values but as I type a new one they get cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know enough about Javascript.  Once you read the docs things become easier.

I was declaring the selected value(s) and then append to the list.  Once I merged the logic it worked.